# How do I find frequency of values appearing in all rows of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, rows, frequency

I have a 161*32 matrix (labelled "indpic") in MATLAB and I'm trying to find the frequency of a given number appearing in a row. So I think that I need to analyse each row separately for each value, but I'm incredibly unsure about how to go about this (I'm only new to MATLAB). This also means I'm incredibly useless with loops and whatnot as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number of times a specific number appears in each row, you can do this:

```
sum(indpic == val, 2)
```

where `indpic` is your matrix (*e.g* image) and `val` is the desired value to be counted.

Explanation: checking equality of each element with the value produces a boolean matrix with "1"s at the locations of the counted value. Summing each row (*i.e* summing along the 2<sup>nd</sup> dimension results in the desired column vector, where each element being equal to the number of times `val` is repeated in the corresponding row).

If you want to count how many times each value is repeated in your image, this is called a [*histogram*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), and you can use the [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) command to achieve that. For example:

```
histc(indpic, 1:256)
```

counts how many times each value from 1 to 256 appears in image `indpic`.

Comment: The `2` indicates that the values are summed along the 2nd dimension (_i.e_ rows).

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
sum(indpic(rownum,:) == 7)
```

obviously change 7 to whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
length(find(indpic(row_num,:)==some_value))
```

and it will give you the number of elements equal to "some_value" in the "row_num"th row in matrix "indpic"